# Proxmox/NoVNC prevent/remap the ESCAPE key

Tags: vim, vnc, keymapping, proxmox

I am working on a proxmox VM using standalone NoVNC window in fullscreen.
Here the ESCAPE key is mapped to leave the fullscreen mode.
The problem: I am using a Vim editor, hence I hit the ESC key 1000 times every hour.
Is there a way to remap ESCAPE in Proxmox/NoVNC to some other key?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Ctrl+c`, it works to me.